# Error in profit margin formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to calculate a total profit margin with Purchase Price(C4), Actual Sell Price(F4), and Quantity Purchased(D4). Currently, my formula is:

```
=((F4-C4)*D4)/F4
```

However I am receiving a #VALUE! error.

Where is my problem?

When evaluating the answer in my case, it resolves `(125-5)*D4/F4)`.

Comment: Are any of the columns missing data? Is it dividing by *zero*?

Comment: The likely cause is one of the cells has incorrect data formatting, e.g., as a text string rather than as a number, etc.  You can test this by checking using `=ISNUMBER(C4)`, and so-on for `D4` and `F4`.  If this isn't the issue, there are some other possible causes you can check against, let us know if that's the case!  PS: if there are string pre-/suffixes in the cells, you can add these using custom formatting or even formulaecally in order to preserve the numeric data type and still rendering the formatting characters.

Comment: You should share your spreadsheet with us for answers.